# How to "insert into table1 (col1, col2) values select col1 from table2 , select col2 from table3"

Tags: sql, select, insert, multiple-columns, qsqlquery

Well I have a question here if it possible to do it. I have a table called "customer" has 2 columns "customer, source".

And I have 2nd table called "balance" has more than 10 columns, one of the columns called "cname".

And the 3rd table called info has also more than 10 columns, but only one row that contains the company info, one of the columns called "source".

So the table are look like the following:

Table "balance":

[image]

The info table:

[image]

So what I want is to insert into customer table from both tables above so the results must be like:

[image]

I have tried the following code, but it gives me an error

```
insert into customer values 
    select cname 
    from balance, select source from info
```

Comment: As there's only a single row with a known value you can simply  `insert into customer values select cname, 'Branch1' from balance`

Comment: the value is different from one user /computer to another

Comment: Remove the `values` keyword

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do you just want a `cross join`?

```
select b.cname, i.source
from balance b cross join
     info i;
```

For an `insert`, you would do:

```
insert into customers (customer, source)
    select b.cname, i.source
    from balance b cross join
         info i;
```

EDIT (for your comment):

```
insert into customers (customer, source)
    select b.cname, i.source
    from balance b cross join
         info i
    where not exists (select 1 from customers c where c.customer = b.cname);
```

Comment: thanks, exactly what I am looking for.  The "INSERT" worked for me. big thanks bro

Comment: can u please help me with another thing, I need to add where (cname  not exist in customer) to avoid duplication, how can I add it plz?